# Errors in R function `maxLik`

Tags: r, optimization, mle

I am trying to optimise a likelihood function using package `maxLik` as follows.

```
library(fExtremes)
theta0 <- c(0.1, 1)
theta1 <- c(0.1, 2)

set.seed(20150518)

X <- matrix(0, nrow=1000, ncol=1000)

for(i in 1:1000){
  X[i, ] <- c(rgpd(900, xi=-theta0[1], beta=theta0[2]), 
              rgpd(100, xi=-theta1[1], beta=theta1[2]))
}

library(maxLik)

loglik <- function(param){
  shape <- param[1]
  scale <- param[2]
  sum(dgpd(x, xi=-shape, beta=scale, log=TRUE))
}

scale.mle <- rep(0, 1000)

for(i in 1:1000){
  x <- X[i, ]
  scale.mle[i] <- as.numeric(maxLik(logLik=loglik, start=c(theta0[1], theta0[2]), fixed=1)$estimate[2])
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error message:

```
Error in maxNRCompute(fn = logLikAttr, fnOrig = fn, gradOrig = grad, hessOrig = hess,  : 
  NA in the initial gradient
```

How do I fix this? Is it even possible? Also what other `R` function can be used to optimise this?

Comment: From where come function `rgpd` and `dgpd`?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. It is in library fExtremes.

Comment: This means that the gradient does not work at the start values.  As you do not supply the analytic gradient, something gets wrong with the numeric one.  Try to compute the gradient first (you may use `numericGradient` in maxLik) and see what happens.